# Magento configurable swatch color option (1.9.1 native) not switching image in main product page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add swatches to a configurable product, which I was successful in doing, however clicking on a swatch color does not change the product image. The color option click event is not triggered.
In product view page if click the media image it will be changed main product image but if i click the color option it will not change the main product image but it will select the label value for example red or black.I have not get any specific error when click the color option.

In my configurableswatches.xml file the following js has been included
 `<name>js/configurableswatches/product-media.js</name></action>
<name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-list.js</name></action>
<name>js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js</name></action>`
Is any other js is missing to change the main product image?

currently site is running magento 1.9.1 and theme is rwd. Please provide me the solution for this.

Comment: I removed the link to the site. Please [edit] the question to replace it with a [mre]. A link to a site demonstrating a problem makes the question useless once the site is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the product page for JS errors (in your console) when you try to switch attributes? Because that's most of the times the case.